# Почему в PyQt5 не появляется окно программы?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Написал максимально простой код чтобы просто запустилось окно

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

import sys

def application():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("пофиг")
    window.setGeometry(300, 250, 350, 200)

    window.show

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
   application()
```

Запустил, но окно программы не всплывает хотя показывает что код запущен. Что делать?

Comment: `window.show()` - поставьте скобки